# What would the commercial application of a conscious AI look like/be?

Tags: object-recognition, pattern-recognition

Sometimes, but not always in the commercialization of technology, there are some low hanging fruits or early applications, I am having trouble coming up with examples of such applications as they would apply to a conscious AI.

As per conscious I would propose an expanded strict definition: the state of being awake and aware of one's surroundings along with the capability of being self aware.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need consciousness? Strong AI would (by definition) give you a replicable commodity that's at least as smart as a human. It may be that consciousness isn't necessary for that.

Comment: Answering a question with a question ?, Strong AI ? What is that, whose definition ? How do you know that consciousness is not required to be as smart as a human ?

Comment: I don't see how there can be any real answers to this.  Given that we barely (if at all) understand what consciousness is, and can't even be sure that other humans are conscious, I think we can only speculate in SWAG (Scientific Wild Assed Guess) fashion about potential applications for a conscious AI.   At any rate, it's not definitively established that a "conscious" AI could do anything that a non-conscious one can't.

Comment: @kenorb - the generally accepted definition of Strong AI is 'as smart as a human, in a non-task-specific fashion'. No-one knows whether consciousness is required for this, so Occam's Razor says there's little point in assuming it's necessity in advance of supporting evidence.

Comment: @NietzscheanAI: 'non-task-specific' and 'as smart as a human' are contradictory in my view /research.

Comment: @Keno - See the definition of 'Strong AI'.

Comment: @NietzscheanAI : Where ? ( Are you talking about that single speculative article): https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~arihuang/academic/research/about.html

Comment: Or Wikipedia, for example. Do you have a proposed alternative definition of Strong AI?

Answer (score 2):

They may be just for fun. If you had a robot that understood you, could hold a conversation with you about your interests, and even had goals of its own (good or bad), it wouldn't really need to do anything special. People would buy it like it was a toy or game.

Also, they might be usable as programmers, artists, designers, anything creative that a computer can't successfully do on its own.

It really just depends on what you define as 'consciousness'. Does it just understand what it's supposed to do, decide if it wants to, and if so, complete the task? Or does it wonder about religion, politics, moral situations, etc. that even regular humans don't fully understand? If it was pretty much just a human, it wouldn't be any more useful than one. Of course unless it can solve problems super quickly and effectively, then it would just be a really good worker.

Comment: Thanks, let's just start with the strict definition of consciousness: "the state of being awake and aware of one's surroundings", i would also like to add the capability of being self aware, I've edited my question.

Comment: With that definition, people and companies could buy and use the AI to do things like making self-driving cars (already done), computers that run businesses, computers that ask and answer their own questions about physics, quantum mechanics, and other paradoxes. A self-aware computer would be able to analyze a situation in much more detail than a human, and apply new information to other things. For example, it took us humans 57 years after microwaves were proven to exist for us to realize they could cook food. One of these machines would figure it out within minutes or seconds.

Comment: I have implemented a system which does exactly this, i say that it would pass the turning test. though I don't feel the world is ready for my system yet. they still have far to go in other sections..of tech...i need more processing speed, so i have being working on a 256 bit CPU which will also be quad call ^.^

Comment: 256bit cpu roughly supports  just over 11579209000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 GBs of Memory

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be simplified, if consciousness means human consciousness then.

What would the commercial application of a Human look like/be ?

So now every one know the commercial applications of Humans.

Answer (score 0):

Consciousness is not a scientific concept. Fringe scientists who theorize about consciousness are generally shunned as psudo-scientific heretics by the hard science community. Conciousness is a meta-physical or philosophical concept.

"I think, therefore I am." is the only proof that consciousness exists that I am aware of. Therefore, you cannot even prove that a person other than yourself is conscious. So how could anyone even prove that a computer program is conscious? What would be the observable difference between a program that IS conscious, and a program that simulates the results of consciousness?

I don't believe that you can program conscious AI, nor could you prove that you have done so. Consciousness isn't something that can ever be marketed. You can only market the AI on the basis of it's problem solving capabilities.